# Numpy array to generic-tiff (tiled) with pyramid structure

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, tiff, libtiff

I need to write a numpy array to generic-tiff (tiled) with pyramid structure having different levels of magnification. The tiff file is to be analysed using [Automated Slide Analysis Platform (ASAP)](https://github.com/computationalpathologygroup/ASAP). I have already tried using PIL, tifffile, libtiff but none of these libraries save the numpy array in the generic-tiff format compatible with ASAP.

The numpy array is very high resolution heatmap which is supposed to be used as an overlay for histology slides to detect cancerous regions.

Comment: Is there a specification/description of "the generic-tiff format compatible with ASAP"?

Comment: Can you explain why the mentioned libraries don't do the job? Are there error messages? Is the file incorrect? In what way is it incorrect?

Comment: @cgohlke The tiff should be tiled and have multiple levels of zoom/magnification like a pyramid. You can get some idea from this description: https://camelyon16.grand-challenge.org/data/

Comment: @NilsWerner The libraries don't give any error per se, in fact the tiff generated by those libraries is a valid file. The problem is that the tool (ASAP) only accepts generic-tiff (with pyramid structure) and throws "Unknown format" error when other tiffs are open with it.

Comment: ASAP uses OpenSlide to read TIFF. The "Generic tiled TIFF format" is described at https://openslide.org/formats/generic-tiff/. Libtiff will be able to create such files. Set the NewSubfileType to 1 on the reduced size IFDs. Tifffile can not currently do that or use JPEG compression.

Comment: @cgohlke Libtiff's write_file() method doesn't take any kwargs for tags like NewSubfileType. You mentioned libtiff, are you sure it's libtiff not PIL?